# How to extract specific items from list of dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, slice

How can I get a single value out for each of this multi-dimensional array in Python. I have tried to print out using a `for` loop.

```
[dict_keys(['section_001', 'section_002', 'section_003']), dict_keys(['section_001', 'section_002', 'section_003']), dict_keys(['section_001', 'section_002', 'section_003']), dict_keys(['section_001', 'section_002', 'section_003']), dict_keys(['section_001']), dict_keys(['section_001']), dict_keys(['section_003', 'section_004', 'section_007', 'section_008', 'section_002', 'section_006', 'section_005', 'section_001']), dict_keys(['section_003', 'section_004', 'section_007', 'section_008', 'section_002', 'section_006', 'section_005', 'section_001']), dict_keys(['section_001', 'section_002', 'section_003']), dict_keys(['section_001', 'section_002', 'section_003'])]
```

Expected result should be:

```
section_001
section_002
```

for each array.

Comment: Did you, by any chance wrote `some_dictionary.keys()`? Since [tag:Python-3.x], `some_dictionary.keys()` does *not* return a list, but some sort of *proxy object* that acts as a representation of the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: You can call `list(some_dictionary.keys())` to convert it to a list.

Answer (score 2):

> expect result should be: section_001 section_002 for each array

In Python3, you can't slice a [view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) such as [`dict.keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) in the same way as a `list`. But you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to slice *any* iterable and feed the result to `list`. Here's a demo:

```
from itertools import islice

d = dict.fromkeys([f'section_00{i}' for i in range(1, 4)])
L = [d.keys() for _ in range(3)]

res = [list(islice(x, 0, 2)) for x in L]

# [['section_001', 'section_002'],
#  ['section_001', 'section_002'],
#  ['section_001', 'section_002']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning it to `x` and then printing `x[0]` would get a single value.

Please revise your question.

As it stands, you haven't given us the particulars on `dict_keys`. You may find https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to be helpful.

In the course of debugging, you may also find the pretty-printer helpful:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(x)
```